# Cannot read property 'path' of undefined in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to redirect page by using submit button in one of my injected HTML pages. but after I click the submit button, it won't work. And I see this errors from 'console'. Can anyone help?

```
angular.js:12477 TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
    at loginCtrl.onSubmit (LoginController.js:112)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:13322), <anonymous>:4:258)
    at callback (angular.js:23549)
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:15989)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:16089)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:23554)
    at HTMLFormElement.eventHandler (angular.js:3298)




  scotchApp.controller('loginCtrl', ['$location', function loginCtrl(formlyVersion, $location) {
        var lg = this;
        lg.onSubmit = onSubmit;


        lg.model = {};

        lg.fields = [

        ];

        function onSubmit() {
            alert('1');
            $location.path('/about');
        }
    }]);

            <div>
                <form ng-submit="lg.onSubmit()" novalidate>
                    <formly-form form="exampleForm" model="lg.model" fields="lg.fields">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit-button">Submit</button>
                    </formly-form>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: don't post screenshots of code

Comment: hi Isaac, sorry for the inconvenient. I just edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case your `$location` injection replaced with *wrong* argument, change it to:

`["$location", " formlyVersion ", function ($location, formlyVersion ){}]`

Undefined happens because **formlyVersion** doesn't have `path`.

Comment: Thank you, Maher. You absolutely correct. it is fixed now.  :)

Comment: sorry, I am not able to change the score.  once I vote, it shows me "votes cast by those less than 15 reputations are recorded but do not change the publicly displayed post score "

Answer (score 0):

In stead of $ location try to use  $state.go('state',{},{reload: 'state'});